# How do I use types to separate incompatible values

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a library for geodetic calculations. One thing I want to include is a type for grid projections (e.g. Ordnance Survey National Grid) and points on those grids (specified by "eastings" and "northings"). A grid is specified by an origin point that ties it to the Earth and a bunch of geometrical parameters. The application programmer can create many arbitrary grids using these parameters. There are also going to be a range of types of grids based on different underlying projections.

Obviously I want to be able to do calculations on grid points (e.g. distance, bearing etc),
but at the same time I want to use the Haskell type system to prevent an application programmer from asking for the distance between two points on different grids. I wondered if a Reader Monad using a type parameter along the lines of the ST monad would work, but I want the application programmer to be able to store these position values outside of the monad, whereas ST is all about preventing the leakage of STRefs from the runST.

I've also got a similar problem with geodetic positions (latitude & longitude) on the underlying ellipsoids. But the grid version is probably easier to explain, given that the focus of this question is the type system rather than geodetics.

I've read up on GADTs and existential types, but I can't see how to do this.

Comment: Might be a way to do this with type arithmetic: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_arithmetic

Comment: "but at the same time I want to use the Haskell type system to prevent an application programmer from asking for the distance between two points on different grids" – why is that? Points may be defined on different grids and still represent the same _physical_ location, why wouldn't you want to allow calculating the distance between such points?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: yes, but that requires a coordinate transform and more complex calculations.  Also in some cases the simple planar calculation is the Right Thing (e.g. when dealing with radars).

Comment: Well, I'd think safely and automatically doing such "complex calculations" (they can't be _that_ hard, can it? Only error-prone, if _not_ handled automatically) should certainly be in the responsibility of your library, In fact I'd consider this one of the major _purposes_ of such a library. — But then, geodesy is not quite my field.

Comment: Its more a matter of managing accuracy and frames of reference. Coordinate conversions cannot be relied upon to preserve accuracy unless you are dealing with a huge table of corrections for local variations in gravity. Take a look at http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/gps/docs/A_Guide_to_Coordinate_Systems_in_Great_Britain.pdf and also the Wikipedia article on the Geoid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two GHC extensions to allow you to mark coordinates with the grid they come from:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

data CoordinateType = Geodetic | OSNG -- etc.

data Coordinate (grid :: CoordinateType) = Coord Int Int

zeroZero :: Coordinate Geodetic
zeroZero = Coord 0 0
```

(The extensions work in GHC 7.4+, not sure about anything lower.)

Then, any functions requiring it can enforce equality of the `grid` phantom parameter:

```
distance :: Coordinate grid -> Coordinate grid -> Float
distance p q = undefined
```

Now `distance zeroZero (Coord 1 2 :: Coordinate OSNG)` gives a type error.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it only works for a hard coded list of CoordinateType values (which I've actually already done using type classes, albeit more verbosely). I want to say something like "data CoordType = Grid Double Double" so that "foo = Grid 3 4; bar = Grid 2 4.2" allows me to distinguish coordinates in "foo" from coordinates in "bar" at the type level.

Comment: @PaulJohnson, you aren't restricted to a hard coded list of values, because (now requiring GHC 7.6) you can use strings and naturals at the type level ("promoted literals"). The documentation about the data -> kind promotion is [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/promotion.html), you could see if any of that helps.

Comment: But they have to be literals too: I can't (as far as I can see) read in a string from a file and promote that to a type.

Comment: None of the datakind stuff is even necessary; a simple phantom type parameter would do the same, as well as be compatible with older ghc versions.